# Official guidelines for using functions newly added to base R

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I am writing a package that performs a statistical analysis while handling missing values. I am using the wonderful, life-changing function `anyNA` which was added sometime after 3.0 ([commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/3766eaef3089ce8f55e30b25337ded6581ea4832)). Another recently added function that people might want to use is `OlsonNames`.

So as I am using this function, my package won't work on older versions of R. I see four options for dealing with this.

1. Make the whole package depend on R >= 3.1 in DESCRIPTION.
2. Redefine the function in my source.
3. Redefine the function if the user is using <3.1 and don't define it if they are using >= 3.1 or make the function check the version each time e.g.

   ```
   anyNA <- function(x)
     if(as.numeric(R.Version()$minor) > 3.1){
       return(anyNA(x)
     } else {
       return(any(is.NA(x))
     }
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if(as.numeric(R.Version()$minor) > 3.1){
     anyNA <- base::anyNA
   } else {
     anyNA <- function(x) any(is.na(x))
   }
   ```

   I'm not even sure this second one would work in package source code.
4. Rewrite my code using `any(is.na(x))`.

My concrete question is is there an **official CRAN preference for one of these**?

Failing that, are there good reasons to use one over the others? To my eyes they all have failings. 1) It seems unnecessary to require users have R >= 3.1 for the sake of a small function. 2) If I redefine the function, any improvements made to the function in R base won't get used in my package. 3) This mostly seems messy. But also, if the base R version of the function changes I might end up with hard to fix bugs that only occur in certain R versions. 4) Code readability is reduced.

Comment: If you're going to put a `ifelse` inside your function, you have to be certain that your default accepts the same set of arguments.  Otherwise setting `recursive=TRUE` will not do what the user expects.

Comment: I would have absolutely no compunctions about option one. Version 3.1 is almost two years old and slight pressure like this is often the only reason why people update / can convince their system admin to update.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes good point. A reason against option 3 I think. There is potential for messing it up, especially as is a primitive function.

Comment: Your second redefinition option should be `if(as.numeric(R.Version()$minor) < 3.1) anyNA <- function(x) any(is.na(x)`

Comment: You could also add a warning for people not using >= 3.1 saying they should upgrade, and define a date at which you'll cease to support <3.1 versions.