# Which R versions contain which base functions

Tags: r

I recently noticed the function `anyNA` which has been added to R base sometime around 3.1 ([commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/3766eaef3089ce8f55e30b25337ded6581ea4832)). 
I only discovered that the function was relatively new by running some code on a machine running an old version of R.

Is there an easy way (i.e. not searching through the commit history, or trying on a number of different R versions) to find out when a function was added to R. In this case, it affects the R version my package relies on and subsequently how I would decide to write my code (as [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226041/official-guidelines-for-using-functions-newly-added-to-base-r)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out just as I finished writing the question, so thought I'd post and answer anyway.

You can search through the release [NEWS files](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/).

Versions [3.0.0 onwards](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS), [2.0.0 - 3.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.2), [1.0.0 - 2.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.1) and [< 1.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.0).